# Syntax Error, Unexpected 'corppress_create_class_shortcode' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, wordpress-theming

Recently decided to update an old wordpress theme of mine for use with PHP 7.2.1. It's been awhile since I've coded in PHP so some things I've slipped up on, it appears. If anyone could help me out with the error listed above that would be great, thanks!

```
$func = function($atts, $content = null) use ($class_list) {
    return "<div class='$class_list'>" . do_shortcode($content) . "</div>"; 
}

corppress_create_class_shortcode('one_half');
corppress_create_class_shortcode("one_half_last", "one_half last");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("one_third");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("one_third_last", "one_third last");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("two_thirds", "two_thirds");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("two_thirds_last", "two_thirds last");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("one_fourth", "one_fourth");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("one_fourth_last", "one_fourth last");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("three_fourths", "three_fourths");
corppress_create_class_shortcode("three_fourths_last", "three_fourths last");
```

Comment: Probably need a `;` after `}`

Comment: You need to close the `$func ` assignment with a `;`.